# use c specifier register and get the wrong answer in matrix multiplication

Tags: c, cpu-registers

I use the specifier 'register' in matrix multiplication in the project, but get the different answer from a standard algorithm. 
The key part in the code is under the comment.
I run this code on the cpu `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz` and get the `Success` output, while on cpu `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz` the output mismatches.

In this code, the `init_data`function just fills matrix A and B with nonsense numbers, and `gemm_nn` function is from the `darknet` source of matrix multiplication.

You can run this code on your pc check the answer.
I have no idea where the problem could comes from. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M_D 1024
#define N_D 49
#define K_D 4096    
// When I use small ranges, the output is correct.
/*#define M_D 300
#define N_D 200
#define K_D 160*/
float a[M_D*K_D], b[K_D*N_D], c[M_D*N_D],c1[M_D*N_D],z[N_D*K_D];
float ALPHA = 2.0;
/**The standard algorithm to calculate the martixs multiplation in the project. */
void gemm_nn(int M, int N, int K, float ALPHA, 
        float *A, int lda, 
        float *B, int ldb,
        float *C, int ldc)
{
    int i,j,k;

    for(i = 0; i < M; ++i){
        for(k = 0; k < K; ++k){
            register float A_PART = ALPHA*A[i*lda+k];
            for(j = 0; j < N; ++j){
                C[i*ldc+j] += A_PART*B[k*ldb+j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void gemm_nn_2(int M, int N, int K, float ALPHA, 
        float *A, int lda, 
        float *B, int ldb,
        float *C, int ldc)
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<K;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
                z[j*K+i]=B[i*N+j];  
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < M; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j){
            // When I replace it with `float sum = 0;`, the output of the two functons will be same.
            register float sum = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < K; ++k ){
                sum += ALPHA*A[i*lda+k]*z[j*ldb + k];
            }
            // When I uncomment this statement, the output will be `Success`.
            // printf("%f", sum);
            C[i*ldc+j] += sum;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(float *matrix,int row,int col)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i=0;i<row*col;++i){
        if((i+1)%col == 0)
            printf("%f\n",matrix[i]);
        else
            printf("%f ",matrix[i]);
    }//for
}

void init_data(int M, int N, int K) {
    int i, j;
    float tmp;
    for (i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<K; j++) {
            a[i*K+j] = (float) (i*1 + j*1);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<K; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
            b[i*N+j] = (float) (i*1 + j*1);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
            c[i*N+j] = (float) (0);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<M; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
            c1[i*N+j] = (float) (0);
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<K; j++) {
            z[i*K+j] = (float) (i*1 + j*1);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int i,j;
    init_data(M_D, N_D, K_D);
    gemm_nn(M_D, N_D, K_D, ALPHA, a, K_D, b, N_D, c, N_D);
    gemm_nn_2(M_D, N_D, K_D, ALPHA, a, K_D, b, K_D, c1, N_D);
    printf("Checking results\n");
    for (i=0; i<M_D; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<N_D; j++) {
            if (abs(c[i*N_D+j] - c1[i*N_D+j]) > 0.0001f) {
                printf("Error: result mismatch at i=%d, j=%d\n", i, j);
                printf("c = %f, c1 = %f\n", c[i*N_D+j], c1[i*N_D+j]);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Success!\n");   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all it's recommended that you should not use the `register` storage specifier, the compiler is usually better at those decisions. Secondly, have you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger to see when and where the problem is? Lastly, I really recommend you use some more descriptive names for variables and symbols. Or at least use comments to describe what each function does, and what each variable is for.

Comment: Oh by the way, if you *don't* use the `register` keyword, do you get the correct result then? And you're sure you never go out of bounds of any of the arrays? And in your `init_data` function, why are you having multiplications with `1`?

Comment: Not that I know if it matters, but it seems odd that you pass `b, N_D,` to the first function and `b, K_D,` to the second one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This code comes from darknet. And I'm trying doing some change. Sorry for the uncomments and descriptive names. The `init_data` function fills the matrix A and B with no special meaning numbers. `register` keyword is used by the origin coder, and I try following their style but get this problem.

Comment: @BoPersson It is used for the `Transpose` to reduce the number of visiting memory in matrix multiplication.

Comment: Have you turned on any potentially dangerous optimizations?